# Changing permissions of /tmp

Tags: permissions, tmpfs

I know that 1777 is the default mode of /tmp on many Linux distros.

I haven't been able to find much online, but I'm wondering if making /tmp group- and/or world-readable is really necessary.

Can anyone suggest a reason that using a mode of 1733 (drwx-wx-wt) might not be acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

For temporary files created by applications, it won't make much of a difference: they almost always use a protected subdirectory with 0700, or at least a mktemp-generated filename. But for temporary files created by the user, it's a major inconvenience – you no longer know what you've put in there, even if you want to just remove it.

If you really want to isolate different users' files in /tmp, do that through namespaces: pam_namespace.so can create a fully separate view of /tmp for every user, and PrivateTmp= can do the same for systemd-managed services. (A special filesystem similar to bindfs could also provide this, especially for non-Linux operating systems.)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much for the recommendation!